# Why allocate memory? (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, memory-leaks, memory-management

I am trying to understand memory allocation in C++.
A question that comes to my mind is why is it so necessary to allocate memory? And what happens if we use memory without allocating it?
Also, I was shocked to see how careless C++ is on memory allocation. If gives free access to memory through arrays with no bounds checking.

```
int main()
{
int *p = new int[5];
p[1] = 3;
p[11118] = 9;
cout<<p[11118]<<'\n';
}
```

The above code works, outputs 9.

In what cases would assigning a value to a non allocated memory location be dangerous? What are the potential ill-effects? Is it possible that the memory location I am accessing has been allocated to some other program and assigning a value to it might cause that program to crash/behave in a very unexpected fashion?

Comment: Your compiler is dangerously forgiving. Any misuse of memory results in undefined behaviour, your results here (appearing to work in the face of clearly incorrect code) are the worst case.

Comment: I'm shocked!  Shocked!  How can it be so careless??

Comment: I tried to drive my car off a cliff, and it let me. Shocked! Now I'm gonna see if my gun lets me shoot myself in the foot.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Why is it neccessary to allocate memory?**
Because that way, you mark the memory as yours.  Nobody else can use it.  It also verifies that there is in fact memory available.  If your system only has 1000 bytes of memory, just picking byte 1500 to store some data at is a bad idea.

**What happens if we use memory without allocating it?**
Nobody knows.  The address you write you might not exist.  A different process might have already started using it, so you overwrite their data.   The memory could be protected; in the former case, for instance, the operating system may notice that you are accessing memory another process has laid claim to, and stop you.  You might own that region of memory, but a different part of the program is using it for some reason, and you've overwritten your own data.

**Free access to memory through arrays with no bounds checking.**
That code does not work... it functions as expected, at the moment, but that is not the same thing.  Formally, that is undefined behavior, so the compiler can emit code to do anything it wants.

**In what cases would assigning value to a non allocated memory location would be dangerous?**
I gave some examples above.  It is also possible to break your stack.  When you call a function, the address the function should return to is stored.  If you overwrite that value through careless memory access, then when you leave that function, who knows where you'll end up?  Maybe the person exploiting your program... a common exploit is to load executable code into some part of memory, then use a bug in an existing program to run it.  Once, on an embedded device I was working on, I had a fencepost error that resulted in my function returning into the middle of another instruction elsewhere.  That should have crashed my chip, but as luck would have it the second half of that instruction was itself a valid instruction.  The sequence of code that ended up running caused the device to gain sentience, and eventually finished the project we were working on itself.  Now, it just plays WoW in my basement.  Thus is the horror of undefined behavior.

Answer (score 18):

The above code is [Undefined Behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). It can work, work incorrectly, not work at all, crash,   or order pizza through Microsoft Skype. Thou shalt not rely on undefined behavior.

Comment: I've never seen it order pizza.

Comment: Fine but this doesn't answer any of the OP's questions

Comment: @BlackBear: Oh yes, I think it does. He asks when it is dangerous? It is ALWAYS dangerous

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan: mmh, yeah.. forgot that :)

Comment: @MK: Lucky you! I was once forced to pay for the whole collection of works of Karl Marx, which my out_of_bounds index ordered through Amazon.

Comment: Hmmm... people always _say_ all these things concerning undefined behaviour, but we must wonder: Has pizza ever been actually ordered consequent to undefined behaviour?

Answer (score 8):

Many good answers, but I feel that there's something missing regarding "why we need to allocate memory". I think it is important to know how the control flow of a computer program works at the lowest level, since C and C++ are relatively thin layers of abstraction over the hardware.

While it is possible to write a program in one huge global scope with ifs and gotos alone, most real-world programs are split into *functions*, which are separate, movable modules which can call each other at will. To keep track of all the data (arguments, return value, local variables), all this data is put on a one-dimensional, contiguous area of memory called the *stack*. Calling a function puts stuff *on* the stack, and returning from a function pops the data back off, and the same area of memory is overwritten by the next function call.

That way, all function code can be stored abstractly by just remembering *offsets* to local data relative to its entry point, and the same function can be called from many different contexts -- the function's local variables may be at different absolute addresses, but they're always at the same relative position relative to the function's entry address.

The fact that the stack memory is constantly overwritten as functions get called and return means that you cannot place any persistent data on the stack, i.e. in a local variable, because the memory for the local variables is not kept intact after the function returns. If your function needs to store persistent data somewhere, it *must* store that data somewhere else. This other location is the so-called *heap*, on which you manually (also called "dynamically") request persistent storage via `malloc` or `new`. That area of memory lies elsewhere and will not be recycled or overwritten by anyone, and you may safely pass a pointer to that memory around for as long as you like. The only downside is that unless you manually tell the system that you're done, it won't be able to use the memory for anything else, which is why you must manually clean up this dynamically allocated memory. But the need for functions to store persistent information is the reason we need to allocate memory.

(Just to complete the picture: local variables on the stack are said to be "automatically allocated". There is also "static allocation", which happens at compile time and is where global variables live. If you have a global `char[30000]`, you may happily read from and write to that from anywhere in your program.)

Answer (score 7):

Allocating memory on the heap allows dynamic allocation of a dynamic amount of memory with a dynamic lifetime.

If you want bounds-checking, you can get it through std::vector::at().

> In what cases would assigning value to a non allocated memory location would be dangerous?

All cases.

> what are the potential ill-affects?

Unexpected behavior.

> Is it possible that the memory location i am accessing has been allocated to some other program and assigning a value to it might cause that program to crash/behave in a very unexpected fashion?

Depends on the operating system.

Answer (score 4):

This seems like two questions:

1. Why doesn't c++ do bounds-checking?
2. Why do we need dynamic memory allocation?

My answers:

1. Because then it'd be slower. You can always write an accessor function that checks bounds, like std::vector::at().
2. Because not being able to resize memory at runtime can be very inconvenient (see early FORTRAN).

Answer (score 1):

In most operating systems, there is a distinct separation between the physical memory available in the host computer, and the logical memory footprint that application code can see.  This is mediated, in most cases, by a part of the CPU called the Memory Management Unit (or MMU), and it serves a number of useful goals.

The most obvious is that it allows you to assign more memory to an application (or multiple applications) than is actually present on the machine.  When the application asks for some data from memory, the MMU calls the operating system to figure out where that memory really is, either in core or on disk, if it has been paged out.

Another use for this is to segment some addresses for purposes other than application use, for instance the GPU's in most computers are controlled through a region of memory that is visible to the CPU as core memory, and it can read or write to that area of memory very efficiently.  the MMU provides a way for the OS to use that memory, but make it inaccessible to normal applications.

Because of this segmenting, and for other reasons, the full range of addresses are not normally available to applications until the ask the OS for some memory for a particular purpose.  For instance, on linux, applications ask for more *core memory* by calling `brk` or `sbrk`, and they ask for memory mapped IO by calling `mmap`.  Until an address is returned through one of those calls, the address is *unmapped*, and accessing it will cause a segfault, normally terminating the offending program.

Some platforms only expose memory to the application that it knows has been mapped, but C++ errs on the side of performance, it never does bounds checking automatically, because that would require some extra instructions to be executed, and on some platforms the particular instructions could be very costly.  On the other hand, C++ does provide for bounds checking, if you want it, through the standard template library.

Answer (score -1):

> Is it possible that the memory
>   location i am accessing has been
>   allocated to some other program and
>   assigning a value to it might cause
>   that program to crash/behave in a very
>   unexpected fashion?

No, modern OSs are designed just to avoid that (for security reasons).
And you have to allocate memory because, although every process has its own 4GB space (provided by Windows), they all share the same xxGB the user has on his machine. Allocating memory helps the operating system know which applications need more memory and give it only to who need it.
Why my "hello world" would need the same RAM crysys 2 needs? :P

**EDIT:**
Ok, someone misunderstood what I meant. I didn't say it's ok and everyone can do it and nothing will happen. I just said doing this won't harm any extern process. It still is undefined behavior because no one knows what's at p + 11118, but ub doesn't mean "it can order a pizza through skype" nor other "exciting things", at most an access violation, nothing more.

Comment: If i have understood it right, your answer differs from every other answer. You are saying that there will be no unexpected behavior (at least in modern OSs) and the reason for allocating memory is not at all to avoid unexpected behavior!

Comment: To clarify what BlackBear said: in a modern OS (including windows, linux, os x, etc), each process runs in its memory space.  So it is not possible for one process to directly modify the memory used by another process.  However, that does not change the fact that accessing unallocated memory can cause the misbehaving process itself to have undefined behavior.  But within one process, you can cause all sorts of chaos.  E.g., you might accidentally overwrite random variables with garbage, or even modify the program's assembly code itself.

Comment: @Yes, Edward understood what I meant. Sadly, only him did :(

Comment: It could conceivably order a pizza through skype if the program already has code to do such a thing and the stack gets smashed in a way that calls that routine :) Modern OSes try to protect against this as well, AFAIK, but it isn't 100%. It could also result in all kinds of subtle corruption of your data, e.g. because p + 11118 is another variable in your program... that could have "exciting" and difficult to debug consequences.